# When using unit test variable in code turns up null

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This is my first time writing a unit test in C# and I am writing a unit test on someone else's code.  So please be nice in the responses.  In the unit test I am calling on the tracer class and setting the voltage variable ctp.Voltagel (it is public) to 1.  When I run a test the variable comes up as null.  I am not sure why the state of the variable isn't staying at 1.  Any ideas why?  Here is my code.  In the constructor of tracerCtrl, TracerParameters tp is declared as private.  So I do not have access to it from the unit test.  I need to set it in TracerParameters.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetScanResultVoc()
    {
        TracerCtrl tracerCtrl;
        TracerParameters tp;
        int channel = 0;
        int dataSize = 500;
        int []data;
        data = new int[dataSize];
        int[] pyrn1Data = null;
        int result = 0;
        tracerCtrl = new TracerCtrl();
        tp = new tracerParameters();
        tp.Voltagel = 1;


        tracerCtrl.processData(data, dataSize, channel);
       }
```

The tracerCtrl Code

```
        public void processData(int[] data, int dataSize, int channel)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (channel == tp.Voltagel)  //tp.Voltagel I get null
        {
            pyrn1Data = new int[dataSize];
            pyrn1DataSize = dataSize;
            for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
            {
                pyrn1Data[i] = data[i];
            }
            bGotPyrn1 = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the variable `tp` of type `traceParameters` get passed into `tracerCtrl`? You instantiate it but it never gets passed into either `processData` or into your instance of `TracerCtrl`.

Comment: @Aaron Could you give us a bit more information about `TracerCtrl`? As in what `tp` is referencing, where the `TracerParameters` are stored in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tp` in `processData` cannot be the same variable as `tp` in `TestGetScanResultVoc` (which is a local variable, and you don't pass it as an argument).

Right-click on the `tp` in `processData`, then "Go to Declaration" to see where that variable actually came from. Then make sure you set the right variable.

Comment: Thanks, I looked it up and the person that wrote the code had the initialization of tp in a function other than the constructor.  Need to figure out if that was done intentionally or due to poor coding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you instantiate `tp` but never tie it to `tracerCtrl`. You may have to do something like

```
tracerCtrl.Parameters = tp;
```

or if your the `TracerCtrl` has a constructor that takes a `TracerParameters` object,

```
tp = new tracerParameters();
tp.Voltagel = 1;
tracerCtrl = new TracerCtrl(tp);
```

EDIT: Didn't notice this before, but I'm curious about where `tp` is defined in the `TracerCtrl` code. I would expect the `if` statement to look more like:

```
if (channel == thisParameters.Voltagel)
```

If `Parameters` is indeed where the `TracerCtrl`'s parameters are stored.

If you update your question with some more information about `TracerCtrl` I'd be happy to revise.